# Can i replace notebook GPU with something newer?

Tags: gpu, laptop-repair

i saw some videos on youtube, that you're able to replace soldered GPU (very risky though)

i have a macbookpro5,5 and thinking to replace gpu with something new (probably another OEM mobile GPU that i'll get on ebay)

is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a laptop's video card can be upgraded?](http://superuser.com/questions/600488/how-can-i-tell-if-a-laptops-video-card-can-be-upgraded), [Is it possible to upgrade the graphics card in modern laptops?](http://superuser.com/questions/1862/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-the-graphics-card-in-modern-laptops), [Is there really no hope to upgrade the graphic card of a laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/397866/is-there-really-no-hope-to-upgrade-the-graphic-card-of-a-laptop)

Comment: ... [Upgrading laptop's graphics card](http://superuser.com/questions/523477/upgrading-laptops-graphics-card), [How do I upgrade my graphics on my laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/428228/how-do-i-upgrade-my-graphics-on-my-laptop)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of any graphics card upgrade question, because a CPU is not a graphics card.

Comment: @kmarsh The OP says "GPU" "Graphic Processing Unit".

Comment: Oops. I have font issues.

Comment: @kmarsh Then perhaps you should upgrade your GPU! :D

Comment: @techi007 lol Thanks for that. I'll find my soldering iron...

Answer (score 4):

Practical answer: No.

You can replace it with an identical chip, but that is only part of the story.

To add a different (possibly newer) GPU you need a pin compatible chip, the right initialisation software (usually on a plug-in cards BIOS, or in a laptop BIOS), sufficient power (a new chip might draw more power), sufficient cooling, ...

Now replacing a broken GPU with an identical chip: Yes, you can do that.

Replacing it with the same model a few revision more modern: Maybe.

But a completely new, different chip: No. Not without rebuilding the motherboard/laptop and the software on it.